# fewer HTTP requests on server - wordpress site

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, performance

I have recently run a gtmetrix.com speed test on my website

The main area of focus on my site seems to be style sheets and JS and making fewer HTTP requests. It tells me...

- This page has 44 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
- This page has 33 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.

Is it possible to combine these all into one? I have one style sheet with my child theme, the rest come from the parent theme and Bootstrap CSS/Js.

Also, Does this have much of an effect on the speed of my site?

Comment: There is going to be no real noticeable effect. You're talking about mere milliseconds. The files downloaded still take up the same amount of space(Given they are already minified).. But if you really want to know of one. Check out https://github.com/mrclay/minify

Comment: consider the use of plugin if it's a wordpress site -- but it's not a good idea to combine JS, for CSS it's ok

Comment: Yeah I have a caching plugin which minifies all my CSS and JS.   So moral of the story is... not something to lose too much sleep over? :-) lol

Answer (score 1):

If your css files are stored on your own server, you can concatenate them into one file in any order.  If your js files are stored on your own server, you can also carefully concatenate them into one single file, but the order in which they are concatenated should match the order in which they are called now, relative to themselves and to the html code, just to be safe, so universal stuff like jquery should probably come first, and very specific custom scripts should be appended last.  Make sure to encase stuff in  $( document ).ready(function() {}), as appropriate.

If your css and js files are stored on external servers as you indicated, then you can either download them and store them locally instead, or you can fetch them all server-side on page load with cURL (or the equivalent for your language) instead of client-side and then assemble them in memory each time you load the page.  Not sure why you would do this, because it would take up a lot of server resources and probably make the site run slower, but it is possible.

Realistically, what I would do to improve your speed is, instead of working on concatenating the files, which will not provide much significant benefit, work on seeing which files you actually need and then getting rid of the ones you don't.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, but I do believe the difference between requesting 40 files versus 1 could be rather significant, certainly if your server will get pounded with requests otherwise. It will allow caching of a single file as well, reducing load on your caching server.